# Javascript - Convert HTML input string into mathematical evaluation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been wondering if is possible to use a HTML `<input id="in">` (which I could enter lets say 25 / 6 * 3) and output the mathematical evaluation with Javascript, I have written up something which very understandably did not work, would there be any way to make it work?

```
function go() {
    var x = $("#in").val();
    alert(parseInt(x))
}
```

Your answers are much appreciated

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What does `#in` contain?

Comment: Please provide me code at fiddle

Comment: I'd think eval() would do it. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Vajh4/

Comment: I'd use eval, but first make sure it isn't dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can using the [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function. Assuming you're input is going to take a value then you can simply call eval(myString) which should return the result.

For example if you execute the following:

```
alert(eval('3 + 4')); // alerts 7
```

Be wary though in that anything you do really shouldn't be saved as this could lead to javascript attacks if someone is able to submit some javascript that will run on someone elses browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do what you're asking; you just have to use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). *However*, using `eval()` is not very safe. since this means that *any* JavasScript code inside `#in` will be evaluated, which is probably not what you want.

A better way to do this would be to write a parser to parse the mathematical expression and build a syntax tree and then evaluate that.

Comment: Well considering the person typing in the page would only be affecting their own browser, I don't see why any malicious results would be anyone's fault but their own.

Comment: @j08691 Of course; I wasn't implying maliciousness in this situation but merely alerting the OP to the caveats involved with the use of `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression parser of [math.js](http://mathjs.org)

```
alert(math.eval('3 + 4'));
```